# Variable name as function argument?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, args

I wish to make a function whose arguments are the name of a list L, and its arguments. The list L has just numbers in it, and I want to round them all to 1 decimal(by the way, the elements of the list L should be **replaced** by the rounded numbers, I don't want a new list M with them). Sadly, the list name varies in the script I'm planning, and so does the length of such lists. Here is my failed attempt:

```
def rounding(name,*args):  
    M=[round(i,1) for i in args] #here is the list I want L to become
    name=M   #here I try to replace the previous list with the new one

morada=[1,2.2342,4.32423,6.1231]  #an easy example
rounding(morada,*morada)
print morada
```

Output:

```
[1, 2.2342, 4.32423, 6.1231]  #No changes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the `rounding` function `return` a value.

```
def rounding(list_):
    return [round(i, 1) for i in list_]
```

Then you can do this:

```
>>> morada=[1,2.2342,4.32423,6.1231]  #an easy example
>>> morada = rounding(morada)
>>> morada
[1, 2.2, 4.3, 6.1]
```

Or if you really really wanted it to assign within the function you could do this:

```
def rounding(list_):
    list_[:] = [round(i,1) for i in args]
```

Answer (score 1):

Close. Lists are mutable, so...

```
name[:] = M
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eval()](http://git-id.conti.de/uidc1485/prop_plugin_l42p)

For example, the following will start with a list containing [1, 2, 3, 4] and change the first element to 5:

```
list_0 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def modify_list(arg):
  list_1 = eval(arg)
  list_1[0] = 5

modify_list('list_0')
print list_0
```

Comment: There's no need to do that sort of thing at all. You could do `arg[0] = 5` inside your `modify_list` function (passing `list_0` instead of `'list_0'`) and you would have the same effect.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this solution either, but if I understood the question correctly, the name of the list is unknown...and the OP _did_ _ask_ how to use the variable name as an argument.

Comment: Quite often what people *ask for* has little to do with what they *actually need*. They don't know how to ask for what they need.